# Using ShellRoute in GoRouter: trying to use root navigator key to break out of a tab from tab navbar

Tags: flutter

I'm playing with the shellroute example from the repo for gorouter.  It has this code for tab B:

```
  GoRoute(
    path: '/b',
    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      return const ScreenB();
    },
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      /// Same as "/a/details", but displayed on the root Navigator by
      /// specifying [parentNavigatorKey]. This will cover both screen B
      /// and the application shell.
      GoRoute(
        path: 'details',
        parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const DetailsScreen(label: 'B');
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

I want to press the tab for "B", and not have it show content *in* B, but rather do precisely what /b/details shows: stacking this window with a completely replaced full screen.

I tried adding parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey to the /b route, but it blows up without running, citing:

```
Error: Assertion failed:
route.dart:408
route.parentNavigatorKey == null ||
              route.parentNavigatorKey == navigatorKey
"sub-route's parent navigator key must either be null or has the same navigator key as parent's key"
```

Why can't I have /b go to a full page display pushing itself on the stack, rather than require /b/details?  There's nothing really to show within the tabbed window for b.  And the assertion is clear as mud... What is the explanation, so I can see if it's a bug that it's not properly doing what I ask?

Comment: ([The tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gorouter/info) for Gorouter seems to have been plagiarised from *[Cloud Foundry – Architecture](https://azureqisite.wordpress.com/2017/01/08/cloud-foundry-introduction/)* (wholesale copying of part of it). And something completely different?)

Comment: [go_router](https://github.com/csells/go_router)? [GoRouter](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)? The former being the package name and the latter the real name?

Answer (score 0):

##### Edit

If a manually defined back button is something that you want to avoid (understandable, the back animation does not fire when using it if I am seeing it correctly), then you can try something like this:

https://pastebin.com/iz8X7hvF

Its nearly the same as in the original answer, with some minor changes:

1. The bottom navigation bar uses `push` if the index matches the index of `network`.
2. The network route is  a sibling of the shell route. This means it can use the root navigator key in order to not be displayed with the navigation shell ( see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117730 ).

##### Original answer

From what I have read on a GitHub issue this is expected behaviour (no bug, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117154#issuecomment-1363412510).

The easiest way to achieve this behaviour is to simply check the tab in the builder method in order to not use a shell for it:

```
if (state.location.startsWith("/b")) {
      return child;
} else {
    // build the shell as usual.
}
```

A basic working example could look like this: https://pastebin.com/4c3mGdYG

Or if you prefer Discord (including a video): https://discord.com/channels/420324994703163402/421448406506930187/1130076296907591750

Comment: The back button doesn't show up when I do this.  That tab is still at the first routing level.  I need a solution that pushes the route, so that the back button works.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz The answer has been edited to better fit your request. (I am not sure if you have been notified about that)